# Parse boolean value to Yes/No in datagridview of vb.net windows forms application

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I'm there is a gridview on a form of my windows forms application. it gets it's value from a data source. the datasource contains a field "IsNew". this shows "True" or "False" in a column of my datagridview. I want to show "Yes" for True and No for False. Is it possible? Please Help.

Comment: Is gridview bounded to the datasource?Show as your code.How you fill the gridview?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448060/422353) is not a duplicate because they are talking about a bound DataSource but I think their solutions are possible solutions to your problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a SELECT statement maybe you may try a DECODE; for MS SQL it should be:

SELECT CASE WHEN FieldA = 'A' THEN 'myA' ELSE 'myB'
FROM myTable.