# how to changed the checkbox to string in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I've a column in datatable whose value would be True or False when fetched from the database.
It shows the check box when displayed in the gridview. But i want to show the the "yes" if the value is true and "no" if value is false. how can i do that??

```
        DataTable dt = DBAction.ExecuteQuery(command,zzz.id);


        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // i want to change here
            gridTagHistory.DataSource =dt;
            this.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322430/parse-boolean-value-to-yes-no-in-datagridview-of-vb-net-windows-forms-applicatio

Comment: You can loop over you gridview

Comment: You should use custom columns rather than auto generate them. Then you can probably use Converter.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your select Query (most recommended)

or

You can loop over DataTable/Gridview

```
  foreach (DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
  {
     string a = rw["YourBoolColName"].ToString();
      if(a=="True")
       {
        rw["YourBoolColName"]="Yes";
     }
    else {rw["YourBoolColName"]="No";}

  }


foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    Label myLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("myLabelName");
    if(myLabel.text=="True")
       {
         myLabel.text="YEs";
        }
     else if(myLabel.text=="False")
       {
        myLabel.text="No";
       }

}
```

Comment: rw["YourBoolColName"]="Yes"; it raises and error cannot convert bool to string. Thankyou for your help how can i convert bool column to string in datatable

Comment: @eeshwr: by adding `.ToString()` it convert into string

Comment: @eeshwr: Pls provide your datatable structure ?

Answer (score 0):

modify your select query to return string instead of bool value ... or modify dataset before making it datasource (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

You can change that column into a template column from design view, then in the markup you can see how it renders, in this case it would render as a checkbox.  From here you can change the display into whatever you want, so you can replace the checkbox with a label and keep the same binding.

[Here's an article that describes how to use template columns.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

This is worth reading even if you don't use it for this case.  Template columns allow much more freedom and customization in the look and interaction with a gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write case in your sql query and write yes or no from there. and just bind it to asp:Boundfield in grid view. simple solution, and would be faster then iterating through grid view row by row.